# UWP sync custom contacts list to outlook.com

Tags: uwp, contacts

I have written an app that creates new contacts on Windows 10. Since you have to create a custom list to store programmatically created contacts, the contacts i add do not sync to the "hotmail" list in the cloud. Is there a way to force this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

When we use the [ContactList.SaveContactAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contactlist) to save the specified Contact to the [`ContactStore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contactstore), it will save the contact to the Contacts. The contact is not in the Hotmail account, it is be saved in the account with your APP.

When we open the People APP and create a new contact, you can select the option of **Save to**. When you select your Hotmail account and save it, it will sync to your "hotmail" list.

We should be able to use the `Microsoft Graph` to add the contact to the Hotmail account. We can use [`Create`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_contacts) method to add a contact to the root Contacts folder or to the contacts endpoint of another contact folder. When you add the contact to the Hotmail account, it can sync the contacts to the People APP.

Comment: Do you know of any examples of accessing contacts through graph? I like the idea of saving my apps contacts to the main hotmail list, but I thought there were permission problems that made this not possible, and developers were therefore required to save contacts to a custom list.

Comment: I have looked at graph a bit more and I think this is not going to do what I need it to do. I have no need to connect to cloud services for this app (in fact, it should work disconnected). I'm just looking to add a contact locally that syncs to the cloud whenever the rest of the contact automatically sync.

Comment: When we create the contact by `ContactList.SaveContactAsync` method, we can not save it to the hotmail account. That it can not sync to the "hotmail" list.